# Spring Data Rest 2.4 Intermittent Error (ClassCastException)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

Working with Spring Data Rest continues. Moving to 2.4.0 gave me more of the behavior I want, however now I am getting a strange intermittent exception.

About. . . 2/3 of the time when I reload or deploy my application, every SDR endpoint with data throws a 500, and gives the following:

```
GET /api/departments
--------------------

HTTP Status 500 - Could not write content: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$ProjectionResourceContentSerializer 
cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnwrappingBeanSerializer 
(through reference chain: 
org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources["_embedded"]
->java.util.UnmodifiableMap["departments"]
->java.util.ArrayList[0]
->org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.ProjectionResource["content"]); 

nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$ProjectionResourceContentSerializer 
cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnwrappingBeanSerializer 

(through reference chain: 
org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources["_embedded"]
->java.util.UnmodifiableMap["departments"]
->java.util.ArrayList[0]
->org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.ProjectionResource["content"])
```

(Full error report available: http://pastebin.com/xzzXkFiR )

Like I said, this does not occur every time I reload/deploy the app, but if it is occuring it's completely stuck, and a reload is the only way to fix it. Very odd behavior, wondering if anyone has any insight.

Issue does not occur if I roll back to Spring Data Rest 2.3.2

Thanks for the help, and please let me know what other relevant information I can provide.

- SDR: 2.4.1
- SFW: 4.2.1
- SDJPA: 1.9.0

Some further testing

Issue also occurs with latest (2.5.0 SNAPSHOT).

Comment: Are you running your application on Windows (will explain myself better if this has positive answer)... also I would start checking dependency hierarchy (in case you are using Maven) for duplicate or inconsistent dependencies.

Comment: I'm running it on a Cent 7/tomcat vm as well as ubuntu 12.04

Comment: can you post your controller class, and your entities please

Comment: @Yassine.b I'm sorry I have been unavailable for a few days. I will try to get this posted today.

Comment: User @Tim created an Issue in the Spring Issue Tracker: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-716 based on this - if you can contribute some more details please post them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bugs in jackson-databind library. Upgrade to release train Gosling-SR3 once released.

See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-716 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-743

Comment: Well I am super glad to hear this has a resolution. Thanks so much for leaving an update! I'll give this a go and see how it performs and most likely accept later on tomorrow.

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that there is another bug and a patch concerning this error that will be released with Gosling-SR3. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-743

Comment: Gosling-SR4 has been released (version SR3 does not exist). The problem is fixed. https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/23/spring-data-gosling-sr4-released

Answer (score 6):

I can observe the same issue after updating to Spring Data Rest 2.4.0. The issue is not deterministically reproducible. I do not have any statistics so far, but it occurs less frequently after updating Jackson dependencies from 2.4.0 to 2.6.0. Sometimes it still pops up, but then a reload is sufficient in my case. A minimal example would help to dive deeper into it.

Comment: I'll work on getting one together and get it up on GH. Thanks for the input and verification!

Comment: I've had issues creating a minimal example. However, I believe the issue only occurs when several api requests are fired off at once when the app is initialized. Is there any way to force eager loading of all of the relevant beans for SDR as a test?

Comment: Further information, it seems as though it can even break for JUST specific repositories? This is the strangest issue I've seen.

Comment: I can confirm having similar issues with SDR. I also noticed a `ConcurrentModificationException` in the logs once.